# FileOutputStream or any creation file using java file is default creating in relative path of Eclipse home folder

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB9Ys.jpg

When ever i use file creation code .file is creating in eclipse home folder not inside my project

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"); 
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "utf-8");
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(osw);
writer.write("something");
System.out.println("new file created ");[enter image description here][1]
```

do i need to change anything in eclipse conf file  ?
its really making me so trouble to read any file.i cant able to use relative path inside the any project

Comment: *"not inside my project"* An app. should not be attempting to write files within its own 'project' in any case. That path will not work once the app. is deployed. Instead store the file in a reproducible, accessible sub-directory of `user.home`.

Answer (score 0):

There is some environment variable that determines where the root is for your relative path. It is easy enough to find out which one, but I think your solution shouldn't rely on this. The simplest way to resolve your issue is to use an absolute path (Something like `"C:/myfolder/filename.txt"` in stead of `"filename.txt"`. But if you want to be more flexible you can add a property to your properties file (or in any other way you choose to add a property) In that property store your root path. and then, when you want to create read or write file build your path with that property:

```
@Value("${root.path}")
public String ROOT_PATH;
...
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ROOT_PATH + "filename.txt");
...
```

Comment: Thanks @michael .. can you please tell how to find "where the root is for your relative path" ?  and need to file should create inside my folder because if i solve this its may resolve my relative path issue ?

Comment: It is most likely environment variable "user.dir" but I STRONGLY discourage you from changing the value of that variable as it may effect your entire OS and not in a good way. Set your own root path either hardcoded or through a property and work with that - construct full path using your specified root and relative path - just like I wrote in the answer